# In visualcode the python package schedule is showing in pip list yet no module

Tags: python

I'm using Jupiter nb in VisualCode (on Windows) and even though in the terminal (vc terminal) when i command 'pip3 list' or pip list' i do see list of packages, including 'schedule 1.1.0'. I also see seaborn, pandas, numpy etc. But I am able to import pandas and the rest, while NOT able to import schedule. Anybodu has any ideas how to hack this issue? Its telling me: 'No module named 'schedule'. But i see it in the pip list. Moreover, i can go to the python shell, open it, import 'schedule' there, and it works, when i write some schedule commands. So visualcode only does not see it. How to solve this, please anybody?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482675/vscode-cant-import-numpy-but-pip-says-it-is-installed This might help, seems more or less the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by **reinstalling Anaconda, VisualCode and Python**. I did not put any path anywhere, and when i go in the environment path can not see the Python path. But VCode is there. Probably somehow Anaconda comunicates via VCode with Python.
Interestingly, now VisualCode says: Import 'Schedule' could not be resolved, yet it Does import it and i can use it within VCode/Jupiter. Now, I can not see it in the 'pip list' command either. Previously it did the opposite: I could see it in the 'pip list' command listed as a present module, but could not import it or use it.  Deep mysteries of the hyperworld.